# Finding unique combinations of two sequence (String) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sequence, bioinformatics

Hello i have a question.

I got two List like that :

`list1 = ['G','C','A','T','C','A']`

`list2 = ['G','A','*','T','AC','A']`

And i wanted in python to find all combination possible of those 2 sequences.

For example the result will be :

`(GCATCA), (GA*TACA), (GAATCA), (GA*TCA), (GC*TCA), (GC*TACA), (GCATACA), (GAATACA)`

Thanks you for your answer

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that.

Comment: You treat 'AC' from the list2 as a single base? BTW, assuming that at a given position you take one value from one of the lists the first and the last bases are fixed (G and A), soyou need to use just the [1:-1] elements.

Comment: Why two lists and not just list1 = ['G','C','A','T','C','A', '*', 'AC']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like Jorge Luis's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75864982/12671057), but also deduplicating earlier, at each position. Then we only produce the 8 combinations directly instead of producing 64 and throwing away 56 of them.

```py
from itertools import product

list1 = ['G','C','A','T','C','A']
list2 = ['G','A','*','T','AC','A']

result = {*map(''.join, product(*map(set, zip(list1, list2))))}

print(result)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3N6cV5ecqZJakFpXk5-cUK2TmFuQXlSgUFOWnlCaXcHHlZBaXGCrYKkSru6vrqDsDsSMQh8DZsWAVRnAVIFktqApHmBKuotTi0pwSoKJqrdzEAg11db2s_Mw8HZg1GmDR4tQSHYWqzAINsJ06CmCDNYGglouroCgzr0QDYowmxOlQH8B8AgA)):

```
{'GAATCA', 'GA*TCA', 'GA*TACA', 'GC*TACA',
 'GCATACA', 'GC*TCA', 'GCATCA', 'GAATACA'}
```

Alternatively, without itertools:

```py
list1 = ['G','C','A','T','C','A']
list2 = ['G','A','*','T','AC','A']

result = {''}
for pair in zip(list1, list2):
    result = {
        r + p
        for p in set(pair)
        for r in result
    }

print(result)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3r-dkFpcYKtgqRKu7q-uoOwOxIxCHwNmxXCAVRnAVIFktqApHmBKuotTi0pwSoKJqdfVarrT8IoWCxMwihcw8harMAg2wHToKYIM0rbgUgAChAcwFCyloKxTAeWAzQAYUp5ZogAzTRJECmw0xBCxey8VVUJSZV6IBEdOEeA_qS5hvAQ)

Answer (score 3):

First lets get all the pairs in every position:

```
pairs = zip(list1, list2)
```

Now lets make a combination for every choice in every position.
To do so, we will use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product

combinations = product(*zip(list1, list2))
```

Lets get rid of all duplicate combinations.

```
unique_combinations = set(combinations)
```

Finally lets join each combination in a single string:

```
all_combinations = [''.join(bases) for bases in unique_combinations]
```

Here `all_combinations` will be the desired output:
`['GC*TCA', 'GC*TACA', 'GCATCA', 'GAATACA', 'GCATACA', 'GA*TACA', 'GAATCA', 'GA*TCA']`. Of course you can get it in a single line: `[''.join(bases) for bases in set(product(*zip(list1, list2)))]`